# jailkit SVN cannot set LC_CTYPE locale

Tags: ubuntu, svn, locale, chroot

I'm trying to set up a root chroot jail on a Ubuntu 12.04 box, and I'm using Olivier Sessink's Jailkit 2.15. I've successfully setup this, using ["How to create a chroot ssh user in Ubuntu"](https://web.archive.org/web/20100316140538/http://www.marthijnvandenheuvel.com/2010/03/10/how-to-create-a-chroot-ssh-user-in-ubuntu/) guide.

However, I also want to allow the user to use the svn command. I have added the following to `/etc/jailkit/jk_init.ini`

```
[svn]
comment = the subversion program
executables = /usr/bin/svn
includesections = netbasics

[dshell]
comment = dpicella shell addons
paths = /usr/lib/tcl8.4
libraries = /usr/lib/libexpect5.43.so, /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
executables = /usr/bin/expect
includesections = netbasics, uidbasics
```

But whenever I try to use SVN within a rooted account, I always get:

```
$ svn co svn+ssh://192.168.1.1/svn/repo/path
svn: warning: cannot set LC_CTYPE locale
svn: warning: environment variable LC_CTYPE is en_GB.UTF-8
svn: warning: please check that your locale name is correct
password:
svn: No repository found in 'svn+ssh://192.168.1.1/svn/repo/path/'
```

As you guess, the SVN repo is held on the same machine, and I've checked that the svn checkout command works with my usual bash user. I have also double checked the htpasswd file that subversion uses (`/etc/subversion/passwd`), and this contains the user name:string-pattern. So that seems okay as well.

Looking into locale issue, I'm not sure what's going on here or if it's the issue, but common sense says that the first error is usually the cause. locale -a within the jailed account gave me:

```
bash: locale: command not found
```

Within the normal account, I get:

```
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
```

I did notice that in jk_init.ini:

```
[basicshell]
comment = bash based shell with several basic utilities
paths = /bin/sh, bash, ls, cat, chmod, mkdir, cp, cpio, date, dd, echo, egrep, false, fgrep, grep, gunzip, gzip, ln, ls, mkdir, mktemp, more, mv, pwd, rm, rmdir, sed, sh, sleep, sync, tar, touch, true, uncompress, zcat, /etc/motd, /etc/issue, /etc/bash.bashrc, /etc/bashrc, /etc/profile, /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8
users = root
groups = root
includesections = uidbasics
```

Looking in /usr/lib/locale, I have:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/locale/
C.UTF-8  locale-archive
```

Could this be the issue, or do I have a couple of issues going on here?

Cheers

Comment: Has anyone managed to get SVN working within a root jail created by jailkit?